# I can't give Token Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, token

MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        Log.e("NEW_TOKEN", s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(params);
        Log.e("JSON_OBJECT", object.toString());

        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "Nilesh_channel";

        long pattern[] = {0, 1000, 500, 1000};

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Your Notifications",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            notificationChannel.setDescription("");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(pattern);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        // to diaplay notification in DND Mode
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = mNotificationManager.getNotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            channel.canBypassDnd();
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent))
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setAutoCancel(true);


        mNotificationManager.notify(1000, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

MainActivity.xml:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
        String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
        Log.e("newToken",newToken);

    }
});
```

This code from MainActivity is **skipped**. I do not know what to do.

Firebase OAuth working perfectly. But without Token I can't check Firebase Notifications. Now is debug-mode. Maybe I must change it to release? PLease help me.

Comment: Is "Log.e("NEW_TOKEN", s); " on MyFirebaseMessagingService.java executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
According to latest docs,you can get new token id from onNewToken Method.<br/>

 @Override
        public void onNewToken(String s) {
            Log.e("NEW_TOKEN", s);
            //Implement your business logic to send your device token from here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the FirebaseMessagingService, you also need to add FirebaseInstanceIdService

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    public MyFirebaseInstanceIDService() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        MyNotificationManager.getInstance().registerToken(getApplicationContext(), refreshedToken);
    }
}
```

Then in your manifest add:

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

Comment: Note that MyNotificationManager is where I am dealing with the token in my application (Sending it to my backend)

Comment: com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService' is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your addOnSuccessListener method removing the first argument like this:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
            //Manage your token
            String token = instanceIdResult.getToken();
            Log.i("FCM_TOKEN", token);

        }
    });
```